# Calculation using if_else statement

Tags: r, conditional-statements, mutate

Is it possible to use `mutate` and `if_else` to make calculations? Or is there another function used for that? Example below.

```
structure(list(X = 1:6, x = c(-50.1298257841559, -49.9523708108406, 
-49.8600298829818, -49.8590735594872, -49.8600022102151, -49.680556540172
), y = c(-29.2498490060132, -29.1594734717135, -29.0700140387022, 
-28.9795033961473, -28.8900003372153, -28.8945716273705), ua = c(1L, 
4L, 10L, 15L, 21L, 23L), species = c(42L, 80L, 48L, 84L, 84L, 
47L), region = c("FOD", "FOD", "FOD", "FOD", "FOD", "FOD"), diff = c(8L, 
6L, 3L, 11L, 13L, 4L), status = c("Ganho", "Ganho", "Ganho", 
"Ganho", "Perda", "Perda")), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

What I'm trying to do is when `status` == "Perda", multiply the column `diff` by negative 1

Doing

```
data <- data %>% mutate(diff = if_else(diff > 0, diff, -1 * diff))
```

Returns that ''the false statement must be an integer vector, not a double vector.''

So, I guess `if_else` is not the right function for mutating my data. What could I use? Or, if `if_else` is usable, how can I use it?

Comment: Try `ifelse` instead. `if_else` is stricter regarding the data types. Or replace `-1` with `-1L` to get an integer. Regardless of this: Your question (`status == "Perda"`) and your code (`diff > 0`) don't match.

Comment: Damn, I went completely dumb and forgot to add the status == Perda portion. I was trying to use case_when() + if_else(). case_when(status == "Perda")...+ the if_else portion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if_else` checks that both the returns (`TRUE` or `FALSE`) are of the same type, since `diff` is a integer, when you multiple by -1 it is considered a double.

So you can either use `ifelse`, that does not check it

```
data %>% mutate(diff = ifelse(diff > 4, diff, -1 * diff))
```

Or you can use `1L` in the multiplication to make a integer

```
data %>% mutate(diff = if_else(diff > 0, diff, -1L * diff))
```